# TestNG : @Parameters does not work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I've started to learn TestNG and this code doesn't work for me:

```
package com.automation;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNg_ParameterTestClass {

    @Parameters({"Param1","Param2"})
    @Test(enabled = true)
    public void testTestExample(String p1, String p2){
        System.out.println("Parameter's value : " + p1 + ", " + p2);
    }
}
```

testng.xml is empty as I run the test method directly from IntelliJ and each time this msg is received:

```
Test ignored.
Test ignored.
===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong, why testNG skips it ?

Thanks for help,
Rafal

Answer (score 3):

TestNG is skipping your test because you didn't pass mandatory parameters to it.

You should be able to do it via the [`Run/Debug Configurations`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-testng.html?origin=old_help) menu of IntelliJ.

Otherwise you have to use [`@Optional`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters).

Comment: Thx for response. What do you mean by mandatory parameters ? Other tests where I do not use @Parameters work fine. In the doc there is no information about additional steps required to use this annotation.

Comment: `@Parameters({"Param1","Param2"})` are mandatory. Otherwise you have to use `@Optional`: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3):

The answer for this problem is rather straightforward.

@Parameters({"Param1","Param2"}) , Param1 and Param2 are the names of parameters in testng.xml, those aren't values assigned to String p1, String p2 during runtime.

The two XML parameters have to be defined, otherwise a test is ignored. You can define optional values assigned automatically to p1 and p2 using the "Optional" annotation:

```
@Parameters({"param1","param2"})
@Test(enabled = true)
public void testTestExample(@Optional("test1111") String p1, @Optional("test2222")String p2){
    System.out.println("Parameter's value : " + p1 + ", " + p2);
}
```

Comment: You should mark your response as the good one to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define those two parameters(Param1,Param2) in Testng.xml, then only you can use it in your test class.

You need to properly define testng.xml for using @Parameters

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<test thread-count="5" name="Test">
<parameter name="Param1" value="Value_Of_Param1"/>
<parameter name="Param2" value="Value_Of_Param2"/>
<classes>
  <class name="CLASS_NAME"/> 
 </classes>
 </test> <!-- Test -->
 </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Check the 5th and 6th line,you will get your solution .Hope it helps.